# How do I create a local highscore? - Python

Tags: python

I am currently writing a piece of code where the user is set a score based on how well they did in the game and I am stuck. could anyone give some suggestions on how to create a local file on the users computer and retrieve it in order to configure new high scores (if there is any) then print the three highest and delete the others to save space.

This is the code I have at the moment but it is in serious need of improvement:

```
print("Yore score is", score, "/30")

if sthighscore < score:
    sthighscore = score
    sthighscorename = name
    print("NEW 1st HIGH SCORE: ")
    print('1: ',sthighscorename, '-', sthighscore)
    print("2: ", ndhighscorename, '-', ndhighscore)
    print('3: ', rdhighscorename, '-', rdhighscore)

elif sthighscore >= score > ndhighscore:
    ndhighscore = score
    ndhighscorename = name
    print("NEW 2nd HIGH SCORE: ")
    print('1: ', sthighscorename, '-', sthighscore)
    print("2: ", ndhighscorename, '-', ndhighscore)
    print('3: ', rdhighscorename, '-', rdhighscore)

elif ndhighscore >= score > rdhighscore:
    rdhighscore = score
    rdhighscorename = name
    print("NEW 3rd HIGH SCORE: ")
    print('1: ',sthighscorename, '-', sthighscore)
    print("2: ", ndhighscorename, '-', ndhighscore)
    print('3: ', rdhighscorename, '-', rdhighscore)

else:
    print("NO NEW HIGH SCORES :( ")
    print('1: ',sthighscorename, '-', sthighscore)
    print("2: ", ndhighscorename, '-', ndhighscore)
    print('3: ', rdhighscorename, '-', rdhighscore)
```

As you can see the code dose not yet store anything. please help.

Comment: Have you tried doing some research on file handling in Python?

Comment: I am still new to this as you might be able to tell and have tried researching but could not find anything on my question so I asked it here in hope people might be able to teach me something.

Comment: This is not a tutorial site and your question is a bad fit here. There are many online tutorials about file handling, including the [official tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files). There are also books: [Python Crash Course](https://www.nostarch.com/pythoncrashcourse/) has a section (Chapter 14) on saving high scores for a game.

Answer (score 0):

To create a local file you can use open() function.You can store score like this.

```
print("Yore score is", score, "/30")
if sthighscore < score:
    sthighscore = score
    sthighscorename = name
    print("NEW 1st HIGH SCORE: ")
    print('1: ',sthighscorename, '-', sthighscore)
    print("2: ", ndhighscorename, '-', ndhighscore)
    print('3: ', rdhighscorename, '-', rdhighscore)
    f=open('score.txt','w') # This will create score.txt text file 
    f.write('%s\n%s\n%s'%('1: '+sthighscorename+ '-'+ str(sthighscore),"2: "+ ndhighscorename+ '-'+ str(ndhighscore), '3: '+ rdhighscorename+ '-'+ str(rdhighscore)))
    f.close()
```

You can use the same procedure to store other values.
To retrieve you can use,

```
f=open('score.txt','r')
data=f.read().split('\n')
print data
sthighscore=int(data[0].split()[1].split('-')[1])
sthighscorename=data[0].split()[1].split('-')[0]
ndhighscore=int(data[1].split()[1].split('-')[1])
ndhighscorename=data[1].split()[1].split('-')[0]
rdhighscore=int(data[2].split()[1].split('-')[1])
rdhighscorename=data[2].split()[1].split('-')[0]
```

Comment: f=open('score.txt','r')
    data=f.read().split('\n')
    print(data)
    sthighscore = int(data[0].split()[1].split('-')[1])
    sthighscorename = data[0].split()[1].split('-')[0]
    ndhighscore = int(data[1].split()[1].split('-')[1])
    ndhighscorename = data[1].split()[1].split('-')[0]
    rdhighscore = int(data[2].split()[1].split('-')[1])
    rdhighscorename = data[2].split()[1].split('-')[0]